# Convert HDF5 (.h5) to spark dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdf5

I have just started learning spark (pyspark to be more precise).

How can I convert an HDF5 file to spark dataframes?

Could [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html) help on that or dask dataframes is something different to spark dataframes?

Comment: Some time ago I found this article: https://hdfgroup.org/wp/2015/03/from-hdf5-datasets-to-apache-spark-rdds/. I've never tried that but it might be helpful. To my knowledge, dask is similar in a concept to Spark but they are two different things (so dask won't help you). I would recommend to use Spark as it is more widely spread. You may also try to use odo library to convert data (again, never tried). Let us know if you find some painless solution!

Answer (score 1):

Read Dataframe in pandas. Then you can convert pandas dataframe to spark Dataframe. This is how I did it. This code will help you:

```
import pandas as pd

store = pd.HDFStore('/mypath')
wav = store.select('mykey')
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(wav, mySchema) //mySchema is optional
spark_df.take(1)
```

Hope that helps!